# How do I execute all the code inside a python file?

Tags: python, file, import

How do I execute all the code inside a python file so I can use def's in my current code?  I have about 100 scripts that were all written like the script below.

For a simple example, I have a python file called:

D:/bt_test.py

His code looks like this:

```
def bt_test():
    test = 2;
    test += addFive(test)
    return(test)

def addFive(test):
    return(test+5)
```

Now, I want to from a completely new file, run bt_test()

I've tried doing this:

```
def openPyFile(script):
    execfile(script)

openPyFile('D:/bt_test.py')
bt_test()
```

But this doesn't work.

I've tried doing this as well:

```
sys.path.append('D:/')
def openPyFile(script):
    name = script.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    command = 'from  ' + name +  ' import *'
    exec command

openPyFile('D:/bt_test.py')
bt_test()
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Here's a link to a quicktime video that will help explain what's happening.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1612489/pythonHelp.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ned's answer, `__import__()` might be useful if you don't want the file names hardcoded.

[`http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)

Update based on the video.

I don't have access to Maya, but i can try and speculate.

`cmds.button(l='print', c='bt_press()')` is where the issue seems to lurk. `bt_press()` is passed as a string object, and whatever way the interpreter uses to resolve that identifier doesn't look in the right namespace.

1) Try passing `bt_press()` with the module prepended: `cmds.button(l='print', c='bt_test.bt_press()')`

2) See if you can bind `c` directly to the function object: `cmds.button(l='print', c=bt_press)`

Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

You should put those files somewhere on your Python path, and then import them.  That's what the `import` statement is for.  BTW: the same directory as your main program is on the Python path, that could be a good place to put them.

```
# Find and execute bt_test.py, and make a module object of it.
import bt_test

# Use the bt_test function in the bt_test module.
bt_test.bt_test()
```

Comment: This is how I would go about doing it, however the bt_test() is calling addFive() inside it's own file, not bt_test.addFive(), and I don't have the time to go through all my scripts and change all the def calls.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: @user1452567 - what makes you think that will cause it not to work?

Comment: Here's a link to a quicktime video I made explaining my problem a lot better.  Hopefully this helps.         https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1612489/pythonHelp.mp4

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `execfile` doesn't work is because the functions inside `bt_test` are limited by the scope of the `openPyFile` function.  One simple test would be to try to run `bt_test()` from inside `openPyFile`.  Since openPyFile doesn't really do anything other than `execfile` you could get rid of it altogether, or you could alias `execfile`

```
openPyFile=execfile
```

Note putting the file in your python path and importing it is definitely your best bet -- I only post this answer here to hopefully point out why you're not seeing what you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from bt_test import bt_test
>>> bt_test()
```